# Generating Functions and closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, closed-form

I read somewhere that we can use generating functions to find closed form of a sequence. So what is the difference between a generating function and closed form of a sqeunce?

Comment: A generating function can *sometimes* be used  to find a closed form.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose that $\sigma=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence of real numbers.

- A function $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$ is a closed form for the $n$-th term of $\sigma$ if $f(n)=a_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. (You can replace *real* with *complex* and $\Bbb R$ with $\Bbb C$, if you like.)
- The *ordinary generating function* for $\sigma$ is the function $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ or $g:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ whose power series expansion is $$g(x)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}a_nx^n\;.$$ In other words, the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series expansion of $g(x)$ is the term $a_n$ of the sequence $\sigma$.
- The *exponential generating function* for $\sigma$ is the function $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ or $g:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ whose power series expansion is $$g(x)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}\;.$$ In other words, the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series expansion of $g$ is $\frac{a_n}{n!}$.

For example, let

$$g(x)=\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\;;\tag{1}$$

the coefficient of $x^n$ in this power series is $1$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$, so the function $g$ is the ordinary generating function for the constant sequence $\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$. The closed form of the $n$-th term of this sequence, however, is simply $a_n=1$, or in functional notation $f(n)=1$.

However, we can rewrite the series in $(1)$ as

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}n!\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\;,$$

so this same function $g(x)=\dfrac1{1-x}$ is also the *exponential* generating function of the sequence $\langle n!:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. The closed form of this sequence is $a_n=n!$, or in functional notation $f(n)=n!$.

If we differentiate $(1)$, we get

$$g'(x)=\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n\ge 0}nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)x^n\;,$$

so the function $g'$ is the ordinary generating function of the sequence $$\langle n+1:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle 1,2,3,\ldots\rangle\;.$$ This sequence has closed form $a_n=n+1$, or in functional notation $f(n)=n+1$.

Comment: Your "closed form" is anything. A better definition is given by Wilf "What is an answer?" Am. Math. Month. 89:5, 289-292 (may 1982). Essentially, a formula that is cheaper to compute than the original

Comment: @vonbrand: You’re ignoring the context set by the original question. I was not trying to give a self-contained definition of *closed form*, but only to clarify the distinction between *closed form* and *generating function*, relying on the very high probability that the OP has seen closed forms and will recognize the intent. (Besides, I don’t think that it’s possible to give an entirely satisfactory general definition of *closed form*, and I certainly don’t agree that your paraphrase of Wilf’s is one.)

Answer (score 3):

The generating function is a closed form of a power series that has (the closed form of) the terms of the sequence as its coefficients.

Generating function for sequence having terms $a_n$:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n $$

Answer (score 1):

For the sequence $\langle a_n \rangle$ the (ordinary) generating function is $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$ (you get other flawors of generating functions by selecting some other sequence of functions instead of $z^n$ to mark the positions). The point of generating functions is that they summarize the whole sequence in a single object (Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) explains this by saying that the generating function is a clothes line on which you hang the coefficients for exhibition). Certain common operations on the sequences (e.g. summing term by term) translate into simple operations on the generating functions (adding), for more details look at the cited book. Translating a problem into generating functions allows to use the sophisticated tools of algebra and calculus to discrete problems, and often provides simple solutions to otherwise mysterious situations. Sometimes from the generating function one can extract a closed form for the terms of the sequence. Even in case this isn't possible, calculus offers techniques to derive asymptotic behaviour. Even when a closed form is available, a simple asymptotic estimate might be preferable.